# Spring Boot 3 with Native giving runtime error

Tags: spring-boot, spring-native

spring-boot-starter-parent : 3.0.5

Native dependencies : Attached

```
<profile>
    <id>build-docker-image</id>
    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <image>
                        <name>native/${project.artifactId}:latest</name>
                        <builder>paketobuildpacks/builder:tiny</builder>
                        <env>
                            <BP_NATIVE_IMAGE>true</BP_NATIVE_IMAGE>
                            <BP_NATIVE_IMAGE_BUILD_ARGUMENTS>--no-fallback</BP_NATIVE_IMAGE_BUILD_ARGUMENTS>
                        </env>
                    </image>
                    <excludes>
                        <exclude>
                            <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
                            <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
                        </exclude>
                    </excludes>
                </configuration>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>process-aot</id>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>process-aot</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.graalvm.buildtools</groupId>
                <artifactId>native-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
                </plugins>
            </build>
        </profile>
```

Build is successful but at time of run it throws error.

```
  .   ____          _            __ _ _
 /\\ / ___'_ __ _ _(_)_ __  __ _ \ \ \ \
( ( )\___ | '_ | '_| | '_ \/ _` | \ \ \ \
 \\/  ___)| |_)| | | | | || (_| |  ) ) ) )
  '  |____| .__|_| |_|_| |_\__, | / / / /
 =========|_|==============|___/=/_/_/_/
 :: Spring Boot ::                (v3.0.5)

%PARSER_ERROR[d] %PARSER_ERROR[p] 1 --- [%PARSER_ERROR[t]] %PARSER_ERROR[logger] : %PARSER_ERROR[m]%PARSER_ERROR[n]%PARSER_ERROR[d] %PARSER_ERROR[p] 1 --- [%PARSER_ERROR[t]] %PARSER_ERROR[logger] : %PARSER_ERROR[m]%PARSER_ERROR[n]%PARSER_ERROR[d] %PARSER_ERROR[p] 1 --- [%PARSER_ERROR[t]] %PARSER_ERROR[logger] : %PARSER_ERROR[m]%PARSER_ERROR[n]%PARSER_ERROR[d] %PARSER_ERROR[p] 1 --- [%PARSER_ERROR[t]] %PARSER_ERROR[logger] : %PARSER_ERROR[m]%PARSER_ERROR[n]%PARSER_ERROR[d] %PARSER_ERROR[p] 1 --- [%PARSER_ERROR[t]] %PARSER_ERROR[logger] : %PARSER_ERROR[m]%PARSER_ERROR[n]%PARSER_ERROR[d] %PARSER_ERROR[p] 1 --- [%PARSER_ERROR[t]] %PARSER_ERROR[logger] : %PARSER_ERROR[m]%PARSER_ERROR[n]%PARSER_ERROR[d] %PARSER_ERROR[p] 1 --- [%PARSER_ERROR[t]] %PARSER_ERROR[logger] : %PARSER_ERROR[m]%PARSER_ERROR[n]%PARSER_ERROR[d] %PARSER_ERROR[p] 1 --- [%PARSER_ERROR[t]] %PARSER_ERROR[logger] : %PARSER_ERROR[m]%PARSER_ERROR[n]%PARSER_ERROR[d] %PARSER_ERROR[p] 1 --- [%PARSER_ERROR[t]] %PARSER_ERROR[logger] : %PARSER_ERROR[m]%PARSER_ERROR[n]%PARSER_ERROR[d] %PARSER_ERROR[p] 1 --- [%PARSER_ERROR[t]] %PARSER_ERROR[logger] : %PARSER_ERROR[m]%PARSER_ERROR[n]%PARSER_ERROR[d] %PARSER_ERROR[p] 1 --- [%PARSER_ERROR[t]] %PARSER_ERROR[logger] : %PARSER_ERROR[m]%PARSER_ERROR[n]%PARSER_ERROR[d] %PARSER_ERROR[p] 1 --- [%PARSER_ERROR[t]] %PARSER_ERROR[logger] : %PARSER_ERROR[m]%PARSER_ERROR[n]%PARSER_ERROR[d] %PARSER_ERROR[p] 1 --- [%PARSER_ERROR[t]] %PARSER_ERROR[logger] : %PARSER_ERROR[m]%PARSER_ERROR[n]
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'entityManagerFactory': Instantiation of supplied bean failed
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.obtainFromSupplier(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1220) ~[com.user.Application:6.0.7]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1158) ~[com.user.Application:6.0.7]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:560) ~[com.user.Application:6.0.7]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:520) ~[com.user.Application:6.0.7]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:326) ~[com.user.Application:6.0.7]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:234) ~[com.user.Application:6.0.7]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:324) ~[com.user.Application:6.0.7]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:200) ~[com.user.Application:6.0.7]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.getBean(AbstractApplicationContext.java:1132) ~[com.user.Application:6.0.7]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:907) ~[com.user.Application:6.0.7]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:584) ~[com.user.Application:6.0.7]
    at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.refresh(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:146) ~[com.user.Application:3.0.5]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:732) ~[com.user.Application:3.0.5]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:434) ~[com.user.Application:3.0.5]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:310) ~[com.user.Application:3.0.5]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1304) ~[com.user.Application:3.0.5]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1293) ~[com.user.Application:3.0.5]
    at com.user.Application.main(UserSettingsApplication.java:17) ~[com.user.Application:na]
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: null
    at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariPool.throwPoolInitializationException(HikariPool.java:596) ~[na:na]
    at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariPool.checkFailFast(HikariPool.java:582) ~[na:na]
    at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariPool.<init>(HikariPool.java:100) ~[na:na]
    at com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource.getConnection(HikariDataSource.java:112) ~[com.user.Application:na]
    at org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DataSourceUtils.fetchConnection(DataSourceUtils.java:159) ~[na:na]
    at org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DataSourceUtils.doGetConnection(DataSourceUtils.java:117) ~[na:na]
    at org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DataSourceUtils.getConnection(DataSourceUtils.java:80) ~[na:na]
    at org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate.execute(JdbcTemplate.java:330) ~[com.user.Application:6.0.7]
    at org.springframework.boot.jdbc.EmbeddedDatabaseConnection.isEmbedded(EmbeddedDatabaseConnection.java:168) ~[com.user.Application:3.0.5]
    at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.orm.jpa.HibernateDefaultDdlAutoProvider.getDefaultDdlAuto(HibernateDefaultDdlAutoProvider.java:42) ~[na:na]
    at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.orm.jpa.HibernateJpaConfiguration.lambda$getVendorProperties$1(HibernateJpaConfiguration.java:129) ~[com.user.Application:na]
    at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.orm.jpa.HibernateSettings.getDdlAuto(HibernateSettings.java:41) ~[na:na]
    at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.orm.jpa.HibernateProperties.determineDdlAuto(HibernateProperties.java:118) ~[com.user.Application:na]
    at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.orm.jpa.HibernateProperties.getAdditionalProperties(HibernateProperties.java:87) ~[com.user.Application:na]
    at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.orm.jpa.HibernateProperties.determineHibernateProperties(HibernateProperties.java:80) ~[com.user.Application:na]
    at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.orm.jpa.HibernateJpaConfiguration.getVendorProperties(HibernateJpaConfiguration.java:130) ~[com.user.Application:na]
    at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.orm.jpa.JpaBaseConfiguration.entityManagerFactory(JpaBaseConfiguration.java:131) ~[com.user.Application:na]
    at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.orm.jpa.JpaBaseConfiguration__BeanDefinitions.lambda$getEntityManagerFactoryInstanceSupplier$3(JpaBaseConfiguration__BeanDefinitions.java:84) ~[na:na]
    at org.springframework.util.function.ThrowingBiFunction.apply(ThrowingBiFunction.java:68) ~[com.user.Application:6.0.7]
    at org.springframework.util.function.ThrowingBiFunction.apply(ThrowingBiFunction.java:54) ~[com.user.Application:6.0.7]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.aot.BeanInstanceSupplier.lambda$get$2(BeanInstanceSupplier.java:204) ~[na:na]
    at org.springframework.util.function.ThrowingSupplier.get(ThrowingSupplier.java:58) ~[com.user.Application:6.0.7]
    at org.springframework.util.function.ThrowingSupplier.get(ThrowingSupplier.java:46) ~[com.user.Application:6.0.7]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.aot.BeanInstanceSupplier.invokeBeanSupplier(BeanInstanceSupplier.java:216) ~[na:na]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.aot.BeanInstanceSupplier.get(BeanInstanceSupplier.java:204) ~[na:na]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.obtainInstanceFromSupplier(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:947) ~[com.user.Application:6.0.7]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.obtainFromSupplier(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1214) ~[com.user.Application:6.0.7]
    ... 17 common frames omitted
```

Expected it to work without error as the build was successful.

Native image was working fine with Spring Boot 2.6.7 and Spring Native experimental without any postgres or Hikari error after i add below on my application.

```
@TypeHint(typeNames = "org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQLDialect")
@SpringBootApplication
@EnableScheduling
```

But after updating it to Spring 3.0 getting the error.

Comment: Can you share the rest of the stack trace? It's not clear where the `NullPointerException` is being thrown.

Comment: Have replaced the logs with the complete logs please have a look

Comment: Thanks. The `%PARSER_ERROR`s suggest that there's a problem will Logback. It can be caused by the required reflection metadata not being passed to Graal when the image is being built. That can, in turn, cause other problems such as the one you're seeing. You've shared some of your app's pom, but how are you building it? [A minimal, reproducible example](/help/mcve) would be useful here.